# Autoptimize cannot write to the cache directory

Tags: wordpress, optimization, file-permissions

I am trying to optimize my WordPress site with the help of **Autoptimize** plugin but unfortunately, it displays an error every time I am activating the said plugin:

> Autoptimize cannot write to the cache directory (/var/www/site.com/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/), please fix to enable CSS/ JS optimization!

I've already searched for a solution for this problem including changing the file permissions of my folder but none of them work. I even tried changing the file permission of `/wp-content , /cache , /autoptimize` folders to 755 and 777 but none of them worked.

I hope someone can help me with this. Thank you in advance and Good Day

Comment: https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/09/demystifying-file-and-folder-permissions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by deleting the first folder `/autoptimize` then activating the plugin again. It seems that I still have that folder since the last time I used the plugin which was not deleted after uninstalling it.